# Python memory leak with loaded attribute in class not getting collected

Tags: python, python-2.7, memory-leaks

I am using python 2.7.14. Can repro on OSX and Linux.

I have some python class:

```
import cPickle

class TestClass:
    def __init__(self, path_to_data=None):
        self.loaded_data = None
        if path_to_data:
            self.load(path_to_data)

    def load(self, path_to_data):
        self.loaded_data = None
        with open(path_to_data, 'r') as f:
            self.loaded_data = cPickle.load(f)
```

You can make a decent sized pickled dictionary:

```
>>> import cPickle
>>> d = {x:x+1 for x in range(1000000)}
>>> with open('testdict.pkl', 'w+') as f:
>>>     cPickle.dump(d, f)
```

And repro the issue like this:

```
>>> from test_py import TestClass
>>> import psutil
>>> import os
>>> process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
>>> process.memory_info()
pmem(rss=8085504L, vms=4405288960L, pfaults=2154, pageins=0)
>>>
>>> t = TestClass('testdict.pkl')
>>> process.memory_info()
pmem(rss=155897856L, vms=4552028160L, pfaults=38241, pageins=0)
>>>
>>> t = TestClass('testdict.pkl')
>>> process.memory_info()
pmem(rss=255520768L, vms=4651646976L, pfaults=62563, pageins=0)
>>>
>>> del t
>>> process.memory_info()
pmem(rss=255520768L, vms=4651646976L, pfaults=62563, pageins=0)
```

Why is the memory not getting garbage collected? Something else doesn't quite add up: `sys.getsizeof(t.loaded_data)` returns only `50331928`, but the difference in `rss` between the two loads is larger than this. Is this a bug, or a feature that I don't understand, and how do I avoid it?

Thank you!

EDIT

For those pointing out that cPickle might have a memory leak, here's a variation:

```
from marisa_trie import Trie

class TestClass:
    def __init__(self, path_to_data=None):
        self.loaded_data = None
        if path_to_data:
            self.load(path_to_data)

    def load(self, path_to_data):
        self.loaded_data = None
        self.loaded_data = Trie().load(path_to_data)
```

running the script

```
from test_py import TestClass
import psutil
import os
import gc
process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
print 'empty process:', process.memory_info()
t = TestClass('testtrie.trie')
print 'first load:', process.memory_info()
t = TestClass('testtrie.trie')
print 'second load:', process.memory_info()
gc.collect()
print 'after gc.collect:', process.memory_info()
```

prints

```
empty process: pmem(rss=8052736L, vms=4405383168L, pfaults=2158, pageins=134)
first load: pmem(rss=9801728L, vms=4406640640L, pfaults=2585, pageins=158)
second load: pmem(rss=11382784L, vms=4407898112L, pfaults=2971, pageins=158)
after gc.collect: pmem(rss=11382784L, vms=4407898112L, pfaults=2971, pageins=158)
```

(here, `testtrie.trie` was build as follows:

```
from marisa_trie import Trie
Trie(unicode(x) for x in range(1000000)).save('testtrie.trie')
```

)

Comment: Before looking at this in detail: There have been memory leaks in `cPickle` in the past. Since Python 2.7 has been in maintenance mode for a decade now, I wouldn't be surprised if there's a leak nobody's noticed. Have you checked the bug tracker?

Comment: Also, have you tried testing this from a script instead of the REPL? Interactive mode does a lot of funky things, referencing objects you wouldn't expect it to. And even more so when more of it was in C instead of Python.

Comment: Did you try calling `import gc; gc.collect()`? Garbage collection need not happen immediately.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Usually I'd point out that CPython's garbage collection happens immediately except in the special case where there are cycles… but pickle has done all kinds of crazy things in the past, and for all I know there could be a cycle between its type cache and the last loaded pickle or something…

Comment: @abarnert result is the same running in a script. Furthermore, I also observe the leak if I replace the cPickle loader with something else loaded from disk, for example a `marisa_trie::Trie` object.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ see revised post...

Comment: One more thing to check: this may not be a memory leak, but a combination of fragmentation and your malloc (or CPython’s obmalloc wrapper around it) deciding that if you’ve used this much memory, it’s better not to release it too quickly because you’re likely to use it again. On a 32-bit system that’s easy to test for—you can drive it over the limit until you get a MemoryError, and then you know it was a leak, or it starts compacting or freeing, and then you know it wasn’t. On a 64-bit system things are more complicated, but driving it to more space than you have RAM may be a useful test.

Comment: But if you have (or can set up) a 32-bit Linux to test on and see what happens when you get near 4GB instead of just over 1GB, that would be useful.

Comment: As for the rss increasing by more than the size: you need enough memory for not just the final object, but the largest set of intermediate objects used to build it. That should be much less of an issue with the trie than the pickle (guessing based on how the trie probably gets built); is it?